# I added a condition when hours, minutes and seconds were less than 10. It would add leading 0. But it does not display (06 : 54 : 08)

Tags: javascript

I have created a `countdown` timer. I added a condition when `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` were less than 10. It would add leading 0. I want the countdown to display like this (06 : 08 : 09) rather than (6 : 8 : 9). But it does not display. 
this is a link: [enter link description here](https://demo6.acb.com/)
here is the code:

```
    const span = document.getElementById('countdown')

    const deadline = new Date
    deadline.setHours(0)
    deadline.setMinutes(0)
    deadline.setSeconds(0)

    function display Remaining Time() {
    if (deadline < new Date) deadline.setDate(deadline.getDate() + 1)
    const remaining Time = deadline - new Date
    const extract = (maximum, factor) => Math.floor((remaining Time % maximum) / factor)
    const seconds = extract(   60000, 1000   ) 
    const minutes = extract( 3600000, 60000  ) 
    const hours   = extract(28800000, 3600000)
    const string = `${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds remaining`
    pan.innerText = `${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds remaining`

    if(hours < "10"){
    hours = "0" + hours;
    }

   if(minutes < "10"){
   minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
   if(seconds < "10"){
   seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    }
   window.setInterval(display Remaining Time, 1000)
   display Remaining Time()
```

Comment: You are adding 'Zero' after making the string.

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933803/javascript-countdown-formatting-seconds-to-hhmmss

Comment: Comparing numbers and strings is not useful, compare numbers only instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few small mistakes in your code.

1. You are adding 'Zero' after making the string.
2. Mutating value of a `const` variables.

Try this.

```js
const span = document.getElementById("countdown");
const deadline = new Date();
deadline.setHours(0);
deadline.setMinutes(0);
deadline.setSeconds(0);

function displayRemainingTime() {
  if (deadline < new Date()) deadline.setDate(deadline.getDate() + 1);
  const remainingTime = deadline - new Date();
  const extract = (maximum, factor) =>
    Math.floor((remainingTime % maximum) / factor);
  let seconds = extract(60000, 1000);
  let minutes = extract(3600000, 60000);
  let hours = extract(28800000, 3600000);

  if (+hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if (+minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if (+seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  const string = `${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds remaining`;
  span.innerText = `${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds remaining`;
}
window.setInterval(displayRemainingTime, 1000);
displayRemainingTime();
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```